# how to retrieve value of textbox inside detailed row of ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I want to save text box enter value in database and this text box is present inside Detailed GridView so i can not even access Directly neither child grid and nor TextBox.

Can any one help me on same

ASPX

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgDepots" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="gv"
  KeyFieldName="LineItemID" Width="100%" OnInitNewRow="dgDepots_InitNewRow" OnDataBinding="dgDepots_DataBinding"
        <column>
     
        //master grid column//
    
  <DetailRow>
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgProducts" ClientInstanceName="dgProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="ProductLineItemID" OnCellEditorInitialize="dgProducts_CellEditorInitialize"
                                                                                OnDataBinding="dgProducts_DataBinding" OnBeforePerformDataSelect="dgProducts_BeforePerformDataSelect"
    OnRowUpdating="dgProducts_RowUpdating" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <Columns>
     <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="QuantityInPieces" VisibleIndex="4">
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txt" OnInit="txt_Init" runat="server" Width="100%"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
     </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```

.cs

```
 protected void dgProducts_RowInserting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
    {

     for (int i = 0; i < dgDepots.VisibleRowCount; i++)
       {
          ASPxTextBox tb = dgDepots.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, dgDepots.Columns["QuantityInPieces"] as GridViewDataColumn, "QuantityInPieces") as ASPxTextBox;
           string payment = tb.Text;

           //ObjInvoices.SellerID = Convert.ToInt32(dgDepots.GetRowValues(i, "txt"));
        }
```

Comment: last parameter of the FindRowCellTemplateControl suppose to be control name in your case it is "txt" right?

Comment: @coder_b yes it is "txt".